# Navigating in and outside CupertinoTabBar View

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

this is my first app in Flutter, everything was fine and smooth util now that I´m geeting a little bit blocked.

I cannot navigate between a CupertinoTabBar and my Login display (that shouldn´t have one) the way I show you on the image.

Login works fine and when receives a 200 response from server, navigates to the view with the CupertinoTabBar.

But when I press on the LogOut button, I´d need to comeback to the loginView, without any tabBar.

The only way I´ve been able to navigate back to login is like that:

`Navigator.push(context, CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginView()),);`

And that keeps my LoginView inside the tabBar in the widgets stack, and what is worse, if I logIn again I endup stacking another tabBar over the previous one.

What could be a better approach for that?

[image: Navigate beetwen screen without navigation an CupertinoTabBar]

Many Thanks,
Gabi

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pushAndRemoveUntil` to pop routes that you don't need in stack. Probably, you want to remove all the routes like that:

```dart
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginView()), (r) => false);
```

or, if your current route is logout, you can replace it with login route and route stack will remain the same:

```dart
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginView()));
```

Comment: Thanks!! your solution didn´t work, because the problem wasn´t there, with the Navigator, my mistake. I was mixing Scaffold on the login screen with CupertinoTabScaffold on the other, as parent widget. Now that I´ve simplified the CupertinoTabBar under a Scaffold it works nice.